# How to get access token programatically when we try to authorize by grand_type auth-code in the OAuth 2.0 like a user?

Tags: authentication, java, oauth, authorization

There is a bank service that provides API to do some operations with bank accounts. To perform a request to all endpoints of this service I, first of all, need to get auth token via grand_type=auth_code; I can easily get the auth code and then access token manually. When browser redirects me to bank auth page I just enter my credentials and then It redirects me to my predefined URL with auth_code.

But I need to write unit tests for my implementation of this API. And how can I perform this process with entering credentials and send request from the page programmatically to get auth code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to automate the flow.

I recently did exactly that - automated integration tests calling bank API protected by OAuth and it took me only few hours to get it to work.

Basically You run a real browser and drive interaction with web page from Java code replicating manual interaction.

Comment: How do we get the token through browser? I am able to get the authorization code but I couldn't find access token in browser. Will appreciate if you can provide insight.

Comment: @sohail when you have authorization code you simply send it to the /token endpoint to retrieve the token. You do not need browser for it only a HTTP client that can send post requests.